# Is $(G,*)$ defined as $G=\lbrace a\in \mathbb{R} \: | \: a>0, \: a\neq 1 \rbrace$ and $a*b:=a^{log (b)}$ a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G=\lbrace a\in \mathbb{R} \: | \: a>0, \: a\neq 1 \rbrace$ and a binary operation defined as

$$a*b:=a^{log (b)}$$

for every $a,b \in G$. Is $(G,*)$ as defined above is a group?

My intuition says this is not a group as I just need to prove three things, first of all..

(1) I need to define an identity element for $G$ this means I need to find an element $1_{G} \in G$ such
$a*1_{G}=a^{log(1_{G})}=a$ and  also$1_{G}^{log (a)}=a$. But as $a>0$ we got that $a^{log(1_{G})}=e^{1_{G}log(a)}$ but dont know how to get $a$ from here...

(3) To show association doesnt hold here I need to show in general

$$(a*b)*c=ab^{log (c)} \neq a^{log(bc)}=a*(b*c) $$

or to show a set $G$ where this doesnt hold.

Comment: $a^1 = a$, so what value of $\log b = 1$? And for the other conditions, how are you faring?

Comment: I'd like to nitpick your thought process: to show that this is *not* a group, you do not need to prove three things; rather, you need to show that one of the three axioms does not hold! That's just one thing to prove.

Comment: Is it associative?

Comment: What's the base of the log?

Comment: It is not specified @RiversMcForge

Comment: You are saying associative doesnt hold here? @AlonYariv

Comment: Already edited my question @diracdeltafunk

Comment: The base of the log won't matter, but generally (for the vast majority of mathematicians) $\log$ denotes the natural logarithm.

Comment: Cos You need to specify what the base of the log is concretely in order to solve the problem. @diracdeltafunk It matters for writing out the answer, but the base of the log doesn't change whether this is or isn't a group (as long as it is a positive number different than 1).

Comment: The operation * is associative.

Comment: @It'sNotALie. As somenone stated before as we are supposing we are working on a natural logaritm then $log_{e} b=1$ implies $b=0$ in order to have $e^{b}=1$ but $b$ is not contained in $G$.

Comment: @RiversMcForge – you're right that if the base is unspecified, then this isn't asking one particular question, but you can write out the solution in *exactly* the same way no matter the base (just write $\log$ everywhere instead of $\log_b$ for some $b$, just as was done in the question statement). Moreover, in this context (any upper-division math class) it's implicit that $\log$ represents the natural log. So imo it's too pedantic to say that you need to specify the base to solve the problem.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk What you are saying about $\log$ implicitly representing natural log in upper division math courses is simply not true in every instance (source: my undergraduate and graduate math education). The pedant in me also wants to point out that, just because "you can write out the solution in exactly the same way no matter the base", doesn't mean that OP can *assume* the solution works out the same way for every base *before they even start solving the problem.* Your reasoning here is handwavey, not to say circular, and unlikely to add clarity and rigor to OP's solution.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk Not to mention, you end up specifying the base anyway, once you find the identity of the operation.

Comment: That's fair – I agree it's important for OP to keep in mind that the base might (a priori) matter. If making sure the base is unambiguous helps OP to think more clearly about the problem, then I'm all for it. I just think it's also fine to solve the problem with an unspecified base – at worst, you'll have a solution to a more general problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a group.

If the logarithm is base $e>1$, then $1_G = e$ is the identity, because $a*e = a^{\log e} = a^1 = a$ and $e*a = e^{\log a} = a$.

The operation is associative – you made a mistake checking this. We see that $(a*b)*c$ $= (a*b)^{\log c}$ $= (a^{\log b})^{\log c}$ $= a^{\log(b)\log(c)}$ $= a^{\log(b^{\log c})}$ $= a^{\log(b * c)}$ $= a*(b*c)$.

Inverses exist. I will leave it to you to show that $a' = e^{1/\log a}$ is a suitable inverse for $a$. Hint: solve for $a'$ when setting $e = a*a'$, then check that the same solution also satisfies $e = a' * a$.

Another consideration is whether or not the operation is closed on $G$, but I think this is fairly easy to prove, so I shall again leave it to you to satisfy yourself of this fact.

Answer (score 7):

Consider the bijective map $f\colon (G,*)\to (\Bbb R\setminus\{0\},\cdot)$, $a\mapsto \log a$ and  note that $$z=x*y\iff f(z)=f(x)\cdot f(y)$$